# Subtracting Times Regardless of Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm in charge of writing a custom report in Excel.  I'm trying to formularize the calculated cells as most of the report is text.  Consider the Following:

```
Date    StartTime   Length    EndTime
1/1/24  13:00:00    2H        15:00:00
        15:00:00    2H 30M    17:30:00
```

I've correctly setup StartTime and EndTime with Data Validation (A List with values between 00:00 to 23:59:59).  In the snippet above 13:00 and 15:00 are correctly converted to 1PM and 3PM.  I have both those columns formatted as Time(The time column is storing an epoch date I believe since I only specified Time) and the Date column formatted as Date: Monday, January 1, 2024.  What I would like to "fix" is the length.  Right now, I'm using my trusty fingers and typing in the Length Column.  I'd like to use **EndTime - StartTime = Length** but I don't need any dates.  I only want the difference in hours, and I know time is displayed as a fraction of 24 hours in decimal form. Once I realized the times got spit out as fractions I gave up as I'd like the Length calculation to not be displayed as a fraction of 24 hours.  This report is for Management.  I need the output displayed in something that's easy to read.

Comment: What happens if the time straddles midnight, e.g., 21:00 to 05:00 (next day)?

Comment: See Comment below RE: Overflow `#####`  I can manually type those as there are only a few straddlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel recognizes them as times, you can set your Length column to `=[@EndTime]-[@StartTime]`.

Then set the number formatting to Custom, and type in just: `h` for number of hours (up to 23), or `h:mm` for 12:34 format. You can include days `d` if needed for more time:

[image]

Comment: No OP is not looking for this, If I have understood correctly, I have deleted my comments which i had posted earlier, OP specifically wants to show the hours as `h H m M` which can be done using custom formatting as well as `TEXT()` functions but parsing the ones which only have `hours` is nt that easy may be it needs `VBA`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya if so, the same steps apply, but type in `h"H" m"M"` with quotes to get `2H 30M` exactly like in the example text.

Comment: I was trying all this while but when it should be only an hour it returns as `2H 0M` which is not desired.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya in what case? `=A1-B1` works correctly for Time values. Excel can convert blank cells or non-time values to `00:00:00` though

Comment: I am not saying the given solution is wrong, what I am trying to say, OP is looking for the specific formatting to display. I have never said the answer is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This works as intended, with the Custom Format Layout of `h"H" m"M`.  There are a couple edge cases, i.e. A row starts at 9:30PM and ends at 12:05A, I get `#####` instead of `2:35` but that's due to the day wrap around.  Also, If the Length is <1H the output displays `0H` but I think I can test for `0H` and remove it using an IF condition

Comment: @eyoung100 nice question, custom formatting is right to use although you cant parse the ones which returns `0` for that needs a formula, however it is always recommended and suggested to avoid `TEXT()` functions while doing calculations for date/times, so that it can used further for other manipulations. Thanks for the question, I was bit confused when the second edit mentioned about `EPOCH Dates` !

Comment: @eyoung100 Excel can correctly understand the difference is `2H 35M` for full datetime values like `2023/11/07 9:30:00 PM` and `2023/11/08 12:05:00 AM`, but it will not go over 23 hours (spills into `d` days). You could "fix" what you have by setting every Start/End time's date to today/tomorrow, but yeah that can be more work than necessary

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, The `Epoch Date` is the default date used in your PC's BIOS, if the date was never set.  It is my understanding that a time provided without a date stores the epoch as a baseline but doesn't display it.  In case you're curious, the current epoch is January 1, 1970

Comment: @eyoung100 thank you sir, for the information. Yes so i was trying to convert the epoch and then get the time difference, hence i read your question again to understand your requirements. Thanks again!

Comment: That's exactly how Excel and every Language starts with Date and Time manipulation.  It uses the difference between the date you're working with and the epoch.  In fact, Unix uses it for stamping.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I inherited a mess of a report from someone who left.  I upvoted that comment, but I need time THAT I DON'T HAVE to implement that fix.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am wrong or have not understood correctly the OP or the given requirements, even i tried to comment twice, but deleted as there was no response. I am posting it as an answer to show what I am trying to explain as far i have understood by the OP.

As OP said in last lines:

> *This report is for Management. I need the output displayed in*
> *something that's easy to read.*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(MOD(D2-B2,1),"h m"),
     φ, TEXTBEFORE(α," "),
     δ, TEXTAFTER(α," "),
     IF(--φ=0,"",φ&"H ")&IF(--δ=0,"",δ&"M"))
```

---

Or, if you want to <kbd>SPILL</kbd> the output then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(MOD(D2:D5-B2:B5,1),"h m"),
     φ, TEXTBEFORE(α," "),
     δ, TEXTAFTER(α," "),
     IF(--φ=0,"",φ&"H ")&IF(--δ=0,"",δ&"M"))
```

---

Only a suggestion, though the above formulas shows the expected output, but it is highly recommended that data used for future calculations should not be converted to `Text` formatted, as numeric times values or dates are more useful for calculations and manipulations.

Also note the above solution assumes, that the end user, will be using the `Modern Excel Versions` i.e. `MS365`.

---